# How to send base64 string through NSUrlSession IOS

Tags: ios, json, base64, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

As I'm converting images to base64 string and uploading it to serer using `NSURLSessionsDataTask` for example-

```
NSString *encodedString =  [[self encodeToBase64String:imgParcel]stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];

[self.package.arrParcelImages addObject:encodedString]
```

and sending it like this...

```
NSDictionary *postParameters = @{@"userID":@"1",@"images":self.package.arrParcelImages}

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postParameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];

NSString *dataString = = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration  delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"image/png" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[USER_DEFAULTS objectForKey:UD_X_API_VALUE]];
    if (strValue != nil) {
         [request addValue:strValue forHTTPHeaderField:[USER_DEFAULTS objectForKey:UD_X_API_KEY]];
    }

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *taskData, NSURLResponse *taskResponse, NSError *taskError) {
    //NSLog(@"Start - Response:%@ %@\n", taskResponse, taskError);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (taskError) {
            NSLog(@" Error = %@",[taskError localizedDescription]);
            completionBlock(nil,taskError,task);
        }
        else {
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:taskData options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            if (json) {
                NSLog(@" JSON = %@",json);
            }
            else {
                NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:taskData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Error: %@",newStr);

            }

            completionBlock(json,nil,task);
        }

    });
}];
[postDataTask resume];
```

But This is not uploading base64 string to server what i'm doing wrong please help

Comment: BTW, the `NSData *postData = postData = [NSJSONSerialization ...];` is not right. Get rid of that extra `postData`. Likewise, the `NSString *postString = = ...` isn't right. You've got an extra `=` in there...

Comment: I had typed it here thats why it looks like this but in code it is perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you're including the base64 image in JSON, you should not percent escape the `+` characters. You only do that if you are creating `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests.

So, do not replace the `+` characters with `%2B`.

---

You are setting the `Content-Type` header twice. Your request is JSON, so remove the `image/png` header. Some web services will just blithely assume the content type, but perhaps yours is getting confused by the incorrect `Content-Type` header.

---

If it's still not working, the problem could either be how you created the base64 rendition of the image or the request is not formatted correctly. It's hard to know without seeing (a) what the final request looked like; and (b) precisely what the server is looking for.

Comment: Your content-type header is not right. See expanded answer above.